# View page breaks when emulating printing via DevTools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, page-break, print-preview

I'm attempting to perform some styling to handle page breaks when printing, to ensure my content does not get cut in half.

I know the styles requried to perform this (`page-break-inside` etc) but attempting to verify they work is a rather laborious task, especially when i can't query the DOM whilst its showing me the preview.

In Chrome (or any other browser for that matter) is it possible to put the page into print mode **and** have it render where the page breaks will be placed?

Currently i can use Dev tools to enable the print media queries, but the only way to see where the page breaks will take place is to actually bring up the print preview. However when thats up i can't interact with the DOM to see *why* elements do or don't get cut in half by the break.

When it all works this isn't really an issue but as we all know things tend to behave oddly more often than not!

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same

Comment: @ahong sadly not.